# Спустить текст в блоке css

Tags: css, css3

Не знаю что нужно добавить в этот код. margin-top, margin-bottom не рабочие, т.к при их использовании сдвигается блок, а не текст.

```css
.text1{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 290px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам нужны внутреные отступи

```
.text1{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 21px;
    margin-left: 290px;
    padding-top: 50px
}
```

например вот тут 50пикселей текст будет вниз идти а не сам блок

Comment: Спасибо) Сейчас приму твой ответ через 4 минуты

Comment: обращайтесь :) тут всегда рады помочь